# Plot cotour graph on folium map

Tags: python, plotly, contour, folium

I've drawn a contour plot using matplolib and i want to overly this plot over folium map or is there any way to draw contour plot on map using folium

This is my code

```
    import json
    
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.interpolate import griddata
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    
    f = open('data.json', 'r')
    
    data = json.load(f)
    
    temp = data['temp']
    lon = data['lon']
    lat = data['lat']
    
    x = np.linspace(min(lon), max(lon), 100)
    y = np.linspace(min(lat), max(lat), 100)
    
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = griddata((lon, lat), temp, (X, Y), method='cubic')
    
    plt.contour(X,Y, Z)
    plt.show()
```

My data file [data.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uRM5alTQxT5ac-VDPGOFLjFMooH9hLKJ/view?usp=sharing), below is how my plot looks now i want to plot this over map

[image: contour plot]

Comment: You can find descriptions of [this](https://www.tjansson.dk/2018/10/contour-map-in-folium/) [elsewhere](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/creating-contour-lines-on-folium-map-with-python-b7994e67924b). What is your specific question? What did not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- it's not clear your geometry is correct,  have reversed lat & lon
- straight forward with https://pypi.org/project/geojsoncontour/

```
import json
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geojsoncontour
import geopandas as gpd

f = open('data.json', 'r')

data = json.load(f)

temp = data['temp']
lon = data['lon']
lat = data['lat']

y = np.linspace(min(lon), max(lon), 100)
x = np.linspace(min(lat), max(lat), 100)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = griddata((lat, lon), temp, (X, Y), method='cubic')
    
contour =    plt.contour(X,Y, Z)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(json.loads(geojsoncontour.contour_to_geojson(
    contour=contour,
    min_angle_deg=3.0,
    ndigits=5,
    stroke_width=1))).set_crs("EPSG:4326")

m = gdf.explore(color=gdf["stroke"])

plt.show()
m
```

[image]