# Contour plot using folium in pycharm

Tags: plot, pycharm, contour, folium, temp

I have a data with latitude, longitude and temp.
I need to draw a contour plot for temp based on the latitude and longitude in folium. I tried this one ..but nothing works not producing a map at all.
Please anybody help me to get a solution.

```
sample_data=pd.read_csv('cont.csv',delim_whitespace=True)
plot=sample_data[["lat","lon","Temp"]]
map=folium.Map(location=[plot.lat.mean(),plot.lon.mean()],
                   zoom_start=14,control_scale=True)
```

Thanks in advance
I'm also adding the next code I tried
List=sample_data["Temp"].tolist()
m=folium.Map(Location=[plot.lat.mean(),plot.lon.mean()],zoom_start=6)
HeatMap(list).add_to(m)
m.save("out.html")

But nothing works .. It also giving an error float not subscriptable'

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70632936/3437504

Comment: I want something like a heat map with Temperature marked in each cluster groups. I also tried the heatmap(), but I have a temperature column with float values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have used earthquake data, as it has latitude, longitude and magnitude
- originally understood that a *heatmap* was requested, so included
- have reused a previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70632936/3437504
- have realised there is an issue with it.  `meshgrid()` needs to use `linear` to interpolate points https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata
- have also included actual points
- now contour lines make sense.  I would expect that temperature data will work equally well.  Hence reason I've used constants for columns in data frame
- further demonstrated it works with temperature data.  Data is from UK weather stations and contour line geometry is within scope of UK

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap, HeatMapWithTime
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geojsoncontour
import geopandas as gpd
import json, requests, io

earthquakes = False
if earthquakes:
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query.csv?starttime=2021-09-18%2000:00:00&endtime=2022-01-17%2023:59:59&minmagnitude=2.5&orderby=time"
    )
    df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
    # df = df.loc[df["time"].dt.date.eq(df.groupby(df["time"].dt.to_period("D")).size().idxmax().to_timestamp())]

    MEASURE="mag"
    LON="longitude"
    LAT="latitude"
else:
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""lat,lon,T
60.749,-0.854,7.4
60.139,-1.183,6.8
59.527,-1.628,7.6
58.288,-4.442,2.2
56.867,-4.708,3.7
54.721,-6.814,1.5
52.242,-2.885,-0.8
52.48,-1.689,2.7
52.225,-0.464,3.1
51.86,-1.692,1.3
54.803,-4.008,5.5
55.627,-3.735,4.0
54.572,-2.413,0.5
55.285,-2.279,0.9
55.02,-1.88,3.9
55.1604,-6.9492,3.2
51.201,-1.805,2.3
53.811,-1.865,1.7
53.031,-0.502,4.3
53.088,0.274,0.9
52.148,-2.04,-0.3
54.614,-3.157,1.2
53.497,-3.056,3.1
52.757,-3.464,3.1
52.949,1.127,3.8
57.077,-2.836,-1.8
56.852,-2.264,3.7
57.725,-4.896,-0.4
50.89,0.319,4.2
54.707,-7.577,1.9
53.12755,-1.97993,2.6
50.354,-4.121,4.0
54.237,-6.502,2.1
52.358,-1.33,0.8
53.093,-3.941,0.6
58.954,-2.9,7.3
56.326,-3.729,5.8
50.7366,-3.40458,0.8"""))
    MEASURE="T"
    LON="lon"
    LAT="lat"

# basic map..
m = folium.Map(location=[df[LAT].mean(), df[LON].mean()], zoom_start=2)


# create a heatmap of where measures are
HeatMap(
    df.loc[:, [LAT, LON]].values, name="heatmap"
).add_to(m)


temp = df[MEASURE]
lon = df[LON]
lat = df[LAT]

x = np.linspace(min(lon), max(lon), 100)
y = np.linspace(min(lat), max(lat), 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = griddata((lon, lat), temp, (X, Y), method="linear")
contour = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)

# plot contour lines on folium
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
    json.loads(
        geojsoncontour.contour_to_geojson(
            contour=contour, min_angle_deg=3.0, ndigits=5, stroke_width=1
        )
    )
).set_crs("EPSG:4326")
m = gdf.explore(m=m, color=gdf["stroke"], name="contour")

# add to folium where measures are...
m = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df[LON], df[LAT]),
    data=df[MEASURE],
    crs="epsg:4326",
).explore(m=m, column=MEASURE, cmap="hot", name="locations")

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

#### output (clipped)

- UIK temperature data

[image]

Comment: I have a dataset that only contains Latitude, longitude , temperature and some other fields, doesn't have time and date. I also tried the above code with deletion of dt.to_period("M") . And my data contain nearest values.. that's why I'm getting only one big cluster structure. How can I  fix to some zoom area and mark it as small small clusters with marking their   interval and scale

Comment: is this incorrect *latitude, longitude and time* first part of your question says you have time...?  I will amend to just do a heatmap

Comment: I'm sorry for that it's temp actually.

Comment: now have solution that does not need time

Comment: have re-worked answer...

Comment: very happy to debug with your data.   add it to question `print(df.head(10))` and paste text into question.  You are allowed to do this,  you can paste any text into a question

Comment: have finally managed to source some temperature data that you could not provide to me...  it's in scope of UK and contour lines are in UK